# Hit Counter in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web, hitcounter

I have the code below:

(Step by step)

1. Put `counter.txt` in `APPPATH . 'logs/counter.txt'`
2. Make `counter_helper.php` set in `APPPATH . 'helpers/counter_helper.php'`;
3. Autoload newly created helper in `APPPATH . 'config/autoload.php'` file;
4. Make `MY_Controller.php` in `APPPATH . 'core/MY_Controller.php'`
5. Any controller should extend `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller`;
6. Echo it on page with: `<?php echo $this->count_visitor;?>`

The Helper :

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed.');

if ( ! function_exists('count_visitor')) {
    function count_visitor()
    {
        $filecounter=(APPPATH . 'logs/counter.txt');
        $kunjungan=file($filecounter);
        $kunjungan[0]++;
        $file=fopen($filecounter, 'w');
        fputs($file, $kunjungan[0]);
        fclose($file);
        return $kunjungan[0];
    }
}
```

The Core :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
 {
  public $count_visitor;
  public function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
      $this->count_visitor = count_visitor();
   }   
 }
/* End of file MY_Controller.php */
/* Location: ./application/core/MY_Controller.php */
```

The Controller :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Home extends MY_Controller {
 public function index() {
 $data=array('isi'      =>'home/index_home');
$this->load->view('layout/wrapper',$data); 
 }
}
```

The View :

```
<?php echo $this->count_visitor;?>
```

The code return an error like below :
[image]

Comment: can you please paste helper related code from  your `/config/autoload.php`?

Comment: Yes, I wrote that [instruction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751089/visitor-counter-and-online-support-with-codeigniter/29753156#answer-29753156) and it is tested and perfectly working. Don't forget to load helper. And to rename MY_Controller.php file like here I just wrote.

Comment: yeah... it's work. i just forgot to load the helper in the autoload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work fine when I loaded the helper `$this->load->helper('counter');`

application > core > MY_Controller.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $count_visitor;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('counter');
        $this->count_visitor = count_visitor();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, must load the helper:

```
$this->load->helper('counter');
```

or

**config/autoload.php:** `$autoload['helper'] = array('counter');`