# Codeigniter: how to make hit counter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make hit counter for each news in my website. I write code in Codeigniter. In view, I use foreach to retreive news and modals to show detail info of news. In google I can't find solution for my problem. Please! Could you suggest some kind of solution or way to solve it.

Comment: How are you persisting the count?

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to put your content quality up

Comment: I just did a google search these might help you get started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684064/hit-counter-in-codeigniter and http://webeasystep.com/blog/view_article/how_to_build_unique_visitors_counter_with_codeigniter